# How can you pick one line from a text file and transform it into an array object?

Tags: java, arrays, line, text-files

Okay this is code and I need to somehow take a line from the textfile and transform into an array object. like p[0] = "asdasdasd"

```
public class Patient2 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int field = 0;
        String repeat = "n";
        String repeat1 = "y";
        Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);



        // FILE I/O
        try{
              // Open the file that is the first 
              // command line parameter
              FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Patient.txt");
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
              String strLine;
              //Read File Line By Line
              while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              // Print the content on the console
              System.out.println (strLine);
              }
              //Close the input stream
              in.close();
                }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
              }
        ArrayList<Patient1> patients=new ArrayList<Patient1>();
        Patient1 p =new Patient1();
        //set value to the patient object
        patients.add(p);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is the pattern of the line which you want to transform into an array and where you want to set it ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing it to console you can add it to `List<String>`

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
   // Print the content on the console
   System.out.println (strLine);
    lines.add(strLine)
}
```

**Note:** your code can be much cleaner, you can handle closing resources in finally

Comment: Okay I need to transform the string into an array like p[0] = "";

Comment: You never know what is the length of text file so better to use List and then you can covert this list into array

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `ArrayList<String>` with `add(strline);`
 and use `toArray(new String [])` to get the array after input stream has been closed.

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 ...

 while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(strLine);
 }
 ... 

 String [] s = list.toArray(new String []);
```

Comment: So initialize it? :p Make sure it's a data field / class variable.

Comment: Put `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` between your class declaration and your `main` method.